# Count quantity of books by category, separate tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 and I need to know the number of books by category, these data I will use on google charts.

I have the code below that I use to find out the number of users by sex. However, the data is in the same table.

```
 $data = DB::table('books')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('category_id as category'),
            DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
        ->groupBy('category')
        ->get();
    $array[] = ['Category', 'Number'];
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $array[++$key] = [$value->category->name, $value->number];
    }
    $test = json_encode($array);
```

Using the same logic as above, how can I get the number of books by category?

I have the Books table:

```
ID   |  Name      | ID_CATEGORY
1       Laravel        20
2       Java           20
```

Category table :

```
ID     |   Name  
20        Programming
```

Could you help me in this situation?

Comment: join + group by ID_CATEGORY. I'm not a laravel programmer, only SQL, hopefully enough of a hint.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Answer (score 1):

You should just group by your `ID_CATEGORY` column instead of `sex`.

If you want to construct such array as before, you probably want the name of category. That would be easy if you used Eloquent. You would have `$value->category->Name_Category` available. If you want those preloaded instead of a query for every value, just add `->with('category')` to the query and you'll have it.

If you are not using Eloquent, you should just load the category table separately, key it, and use `$categories[$value->ID_CATEGORY]->Name_Category`.

#### Other comments

- `DB::raw('sex as sex')` is equivalent to `sex`.
- `++$key` seems redundant, you could just push to the end by assigning to `$array[]`.
- Array with a header row is not very JSON. Typically you'd have `key:value` pairs all of the time.
- You can construct the array using [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections) methods.
- If you don't have good reasons for the opposite, you should stick to Laravel naming conventions.

I would probably not create an array myself, but do your example as something like this:

```
$stats = User::select('sex', DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
             ->groupBy('sex')
             ->get();

$stats->setVisible(['sex', 'number']);

return $stats;
```

Comment: I edited it following its logic, but it didn't work.

I must be getting it wrong